# Excel VBA - mkdir with variable names

Tags: excel, vba, syntax, mkdir

I have a macro that copies data into a workbook and saves the workbook as a combination of variables in the input workbook.  Here is what I'm using to do that:

```
ActiveWorkbook.saveas "D:\sm031648\Documents\Lighting Audits\" & Accnt & " -     " & Property & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

I would like to add an if statement and mkdir before so that it saves it within a folder of the same name, and creates the folder in the directory if one is not already there.  As I type in the below code above this part with variable names, I get "Compile Error; Expected end of statement".  What am I missing?

```
If Len(Dir("D:\sm031648\Documents\Lighting Audits\" & Accnt & " - " Property, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir "D:\sm031648\Documents\Lighting Audits\" & Accnt & " - " Property
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the & before Property.

```
If Len(Dir("C:\sm031648\Documents\Lighting Audits\" & Accnt & " - " & Property, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir "C:\sm031648\Documents\Lighting Audits\" & Accnt & " - " & Property
End If
```

Comment: That's it!  Thank you.